# Querying Elasticsearch Index from Python returns 0 hits but thousands from Kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to query from Jupyter a Elasticsearch index using Python. This is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

esHost="http://myhost.com:9600"
esUser="myuser"
esPass="mypass"
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=esHost, http_auth=(esUser, esPass))

query = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "pkey"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

res = es.search(index="myindex", doc_type="articles", body=query)
res
```

The result I am getting is:

```
{'took': 1,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 6, 'successful': 6, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

However, when I run the same query in Kibana:

```
GET /myindex/_search?
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "pkey"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I am getting thousands of results:

```
{
  "took" : 67,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 12605121,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      { 
     ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably remove `doc_type="articles"` in your Python code, since this is the only difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `doc_type` in your python code, since this seems to be the only difference

```
res = es.search(index="myindex", doc_type="articles", body=query)
                                       ^
                                       |
                              remove this parameter
```